# Why do I get nedb error "You cannot mix modifiers and normal fields" on update

Tags: javascript, nedb

I try to update an nedb document using basically the following code:

```
  var doc =   {
        "$set": {
            "freimessen.messungen": [
                {
                    "Intervall": "kein",
                    "messvorlage": 9,
                    "startzeit": "2021-04-21T16:00:00.000Z",
                    "gaspruefer": 1,
                    "kommentar": "Bitte sorgfältig messen :)",
                    "nummer": 1,
                    "befahrungid": 75,
                    "csenummer": "EPTW-00075-01",
                    "cseid": "288"
                }
            ],
            "status": {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Messungen beauftragt"
            }
        }
    };

var idobj = { 'id': 35 };

mydb.update(idobj, doc, {}, function (err, numreplaced) {
                   // error handling
                });
```

But nedb complains: **You cannot mix modifiers and normal fields**

what is wrong with the update document? I want to update the whole array in the field freimessung.messungen. All items need to get a new field "befahrungId", so I basically read the document, add befahrungId to every item in the array and update, but that does not seem to work this way.

Do I really need to update each array item individually?

Comment: I tried to run your code and it works, I can't see any modifiers mixed with with normal fields. Are you sure this is exactly the same code that throws the error? Regarding updating the array. In your example you replace the old `messungen` array with a new single element array. I guess this is not your intention right? Do you rather want to push new elements to the existing `messungen` array?

Comment: the actual code is wrapped into promises but is basically the same. The only difference is that the updated record is quite complex in reality and I update it only partially. Weird that it works for you. Yes, I want to update the old array - that is the intention, because all elements are modified (its a single element in the example).

Comment: Weird, it works for me too when I try it in  https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-cdn-6dvxo?file=/src/index.js

Comment: in your application, are you calling the nedb methods directly or is there a wrapper like feathers-nedb or similar?